# Laravel showing directory file instead of redirecting to public/index.php

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, centos7

I am kinda new to Laravel and I am trying to do the next thing:

I have a Centos 7 running Apache and PHP on which I have different web apps running.

I have all apps in `/var/www/html` under folders and `index.php` links them all. Now i installed composer, Laravel and added a new Laravel project in `/var/www/html/play/play1`.

The problem is that when I try to access `https://example.com/play/play1` I should get the Laravel index page (the one under `public/index.php`) correct?

Instead I get a directory with all Laravel project files.
If I access `https://example.com/play/play1/public` I can see the index page.

I've searched it over and I checked if `AllowOverwrite` all is present, if `mod_rewrite` is on. Inside public folder there is a `.htaccess` file.

Can anybody who dealt which such a problem help me please ?

Comment: That does sound that the .htaccess is not being read, if you access domain.com/index.php the website does load correctly right?

Answer (score 8):

Within the root of the project folder (where you see app/ resources folders etc) create a .htaccess file and paste the below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

        # Handle Authorization Header
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's root directory should not be the one accessed publicly - you have to point to `public/` directory (where the `index.php` and `.htaccess` are located).

So in your server config `http://example.com/play/play1` should point to `var/www/html/play/play1/public`